# Activate timeago on newly added elements only

Tags: jquery, timeago

I'm trying to fix the problem of not repeating the timeago function to elements that have it already, but adding it to the ones that don't have it. I'm trying this but newly added abbrs are not getting activated

```
<abbr title="2011-09-15T12:46:26" class="timeago">less than a minute ago</abbr>


function activate_timeago(){
        setInterval(function(){
            $('.timeago').each(function(){
                if ($(this).data('active')!='yes'){
                    $(this).timeago();
                    $(this).data('active','yes');   
                }
            });
        },60000);
    }
```

any ideas?

Comment: You aren't really saying what you're wanting to add "it" to -- it's not even clear if you're referring to the class name or something else.

Answer (score 2):

i would not activate them with an interval like you are trying, but rather immediately when creating the new item, just call a function like this one

```
function activate_timeago(el){
    $(el).each(function(){
        if (!$(this).hasClass('processed')){
            $(this).timeago();
            $(this).addClass('processed');   
        }
    });
}
```

after the ajax callback for fetching new items is done, just call:

```
var elements = $('#container .new');
activate_timeago(elements);
```

**edit**
just so there is no confusion, the `$('#container .new')` selector is not default jQuery, `new` is a css class like any other class, you could add the class `new` to your elements when you do the ajaxcall, or you could select them in another way since you probably have just added them to the DOM in your ajax callback you already might have them available in an array ...
**end edit**

but,
if you really want to continue on the interval part use this:

```
function activate_timeago(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $('.timeago:not(.processed)').each(function(){
                $(this).timeago();
                $(this).addClass('processed');
            }
        });
    },60000);
}
```

this function you'd only call once at the page load, 
downside of option two, they are not made into timeago immediately, but only after the next time the interval hits.

Comment: i did add some extra clarification in an Edit to my answer, because i thought it could be misunderstood :)

Answer (score 0):

ok this seems to work

```
function activate_timeago(){
    $('.timeago').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.data('active')!='yes'){
            $this.timeago().data('active','yes');    
        }
    });
    setTimeout(activate_timeago, 60000);
}
```

Thanks to eddiemonge on #jquery

Comment: this is a good solution (if you don't mind the fact that your abbr's will only be switched into timeago once every 60 seconds),  for real time timeago as soon as your elements are loaded, you could follow my first solution. your choice really...